# JMeter - Dashboard Statistics Percentile

Tags: jmeter

Referring to: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

I have a load test that does CRUD process (eg process 1 is create, 2 is Read).  In each process, I need to execute several http samples. So:

```
Create: C1, C2, C3
Read:   R1, R2
Update: U1, U2, U3, U4
Delete: D1, D2, D3, D4
```

After running the load test, the Statistics table (in the main Dashboard page below the "Test and Report information" table), there is a Total & 90th, 95th, 99th pct.

[image]

Is it right to say that the Total Pct Response Time be the pct for all the http samples, (ie C1, C2, C3, R1, R2, U1, U2, U3, U4, D1, D2, D3, D4).  In this case, this Total PCT won't be very useful because it "bundles" the different process http samples together and it won't give a good picture of response time by the individual processes, right ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) as:

  ```
  jmeter -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
  ```

  the [result.jtl is basically CSV file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) containing different metrics.
- Percentiles are calculated from [`elapsed` column](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) which contains the time from just before sending the request till the last byte of the response is received

If you don't find it "useful" - you're free to ignore the value but many people find it useful and configure "Total" percentile as a custom failure criteria in [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance) or [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/).

Comment: I mean in my example, this default Total would combine all http samples for the different CRUD process ?  It my understanding correct ?

Comment: It will calculate given percentiles for all response times for all samplers